# PayPal Permissions API GetAccessToken API call not working

Tags: paypal

Error back from API call is below:

```
{error(0).message=Internal+Error, error(0).errorId=520002, error(0).subdomain=Application, error(0).category=Application, responseEnvelope.correlationId=46cac792dc1a4, error(0).domain=PLATFORM, responseEnvelope.ack=Failure, error(0).severity=Error}
```

How do I even debug this? Nothing in the error to help me debug this, everything seems fine code is all against a sandbox and nothing seems suspicious. Any suggestion on debugging this would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you are using to get the Token

Comment: The problem was I had token and token secret assigned other way around in the API call (GetAccessToken), its solved. PayPal definitely need to work on their validation error message to make it more intuitive. This was definitely "NOT" and internal error.....

Comment: I agree, Paypal has the worst documentation and error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal needs a better documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the code, so that it will help me/others to understand where the problem lies..

Make sure you are using the correct URL.

For Sandbox, the GetAccessToken URL is https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/GetAccessToken

The following parameters need to passed while making the call to 'GetAccessToken' URL

- requestEnvelope.errorLanguage
- token (request token)
- verifier(verification code)